# C# method CheckSignature returns false for valid XAdES signed document

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xades

I try to implement XAdES signature verification in C#. 
It works fine for sample documents like [this](https://pastebin.com/30Jt9Mcj).
However on actual document like [this](https://pastebin.com/q37x93Py) method CheckSignature returns false, even though it is a valid document (additionally verified [here](https://weryfikacjapodpisu.pl/verification/#dropzone)).

Here's my code

```cs
public bool Verify(Stream xmlFileStream)
{
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(xmlFileStream);

    var signatureNodes = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("ds:Signature");
    if (signatureNodes == null || signatureNodes.Count != 1)
    {
        throw new Exception("Wrong number of signature nodes in document");
    }

    var signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
    signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)signatureNodes[0]);            
    var signatureValid = signedXml.CheckSignature();
    return signatureValid;
}
```

I've tried loading xml with and without preserving whitespaces, even tried removing namespaces from the document, nothing is working.

**EDIT**
I've turned on diagnostic logging and it says

```
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml Information: 12: [SignedXml # 0060fb3c, VerificationFailure] Verification failed while checking the Reference.
```

Unfortunately it doesn't say much to me, I still have no idea why the reference verification fail here while it seems ok for online verification service.

Comment: The .`PreserveWhiteSpace = true` is necessary. Does the document contain the certificate in the KeyInfo/X509Data?

Comment: @WiktorZychla As i mentioned I've tried setting `PreserveWhiteSpace = true`. The document contains certificate in ds:KeyInfo/ds:X509Data